# iPhone camera controls are misaligned

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-camera

For some reason my camera controls are misaligned and are displaying cut off at the top of the screen. Below is the code that I've implemented to use the camera, is there anything that could fix this?

```
- (void)takePhoto {
     UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }
    [MAINVIEWCONTROLLER presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [wantsFullScreenLayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/wantsFullScreenLayout) and set it accordingly.

If you want full screen, you will also need to hide the status bar using [setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden%3awithAnimation%3a)

Comment: Awesome! That did it thanks! I was thinking that I'd have to manually move the camera controls, but it makes perfect sense to hide the status bar when taking a picture.